# Rails asset pipeline serves old manifests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Precompiling assets on the servers was taking a long time with a **Rails 4.0.0** app and sometimes the process got killed so I switched to doing it locally, zipping it and uploading it to the servers instead.

It solved the speed problem. But Im running into another issue where the latest assets that have been uploaded to the server are not being served by my Rails servers even if they have been restarted repeatedly.

To illustrate this, the version of `application.css` that's being served now by our app in production is `application-dc02e058cd956b2492c840315ccbff7f.css`

The manifest files available on the server are -

```
ubuntu@production-app01:/mnt/snapshot-production/current/public/assets$ ls -lt manifest-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app app 203032 Jan 17 05:32 manifest-3365253428e645b923e834b54fb530ea.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app app 203032 Jan  6 17:02 manifest-44c2495f77ae0b10489563653d482136.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app app 203032 Dec 30 08:53 manifest-bbe38eefd3a3671b8d1d7bf524307413.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app app 203212 Dec 30 08:36 manifest-7fde3fe5c6247d724bf36a7aa9baee53.json
```

If I try to find which manifests refer to the currently served application.css, I get the following -

```
ubuntu@production-app01:/mnt/snapshot-production/current/public/assets$ grep -rl application-dc02e058cd956b2492c840315ccbff7f.css manifest-*.json                                                 
manifest-44c2495f77ae0b10489563653d482136.json
manifest-7fde3fe5c6247d724bf36a7aa9baee53.json
manifest-bbe38eefd3a3671b8d1d7bf524307413.json
```

As you can see, it is being served from the 3 older versions of the manifest files I have.

If I try to find what version of `application.css` is being served from my latest manifest file (Jan 17) - `manifest-3365253428e645b923e834b54fb530ea.json` -

```
ubuntu@production-app01:/mnt/snapshot-production/current/public/assets$ grep -Po application*.css manifest-3365253428e645b923e834b54fb530ea.json
manifest-3365253428e645b923e834b54fb530ea.json:application-58eb91ccbe7698274d351e16b9b281aa.css
manifest-3365253428e645b923e834b54fb530ea.json:application-58eb91ccbe7698274d351e16b9b281aa.css
```

As you can see its a totally different one and this is what I expect my app servers to serve out now. But its not happening unfortunately leading to issues many times.

But one thing I have noticed but have no explanation is, sometimes it works fine. The latest version is served after certain deploys.

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* have more than one manifest file in your assets directory. That is your problem.

Rails (actually Sprockets) picks the first manifest file it finds ([source](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/2d30e546872f6f4c5361fe19c2d89b15c5db2dd4/lib/sprockets/manifest_utils.rb#L36)). It might be new, it might be old; there is no guarantee. A manifest uses a [completely random](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/2d30e546872f6f4c5361fe19c2d89b15c5db2dd4/lib/sprockets/manifest_utils.rb#L23) filename. The only way you can guarantee the right manifest is used is if there is only one manifest file.

Start by downloading the manifest that your server is using, run `assets:precompile` on top of that to update it, then re-upload. Otherwise you'll be creating a new manifest each time you precompile, leading to these problems.

Comment: Ahh!! I see. Thanks Matt. And thanks for the tip about downloading the assets. That's a great idea. Never thought of that. Thanks.